# TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY in ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

In Honeycomb I was able to create a system overlay with TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY and receive touches with FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH.

Now ICS has changed something. I can still create the system overlay, but i can't get touches.

Now, i am able to create the same with TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT and get touches, but it just catches the touchevents, and not passing them on like in Honeycomb.

Any idea's?

Kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything you describe is true. It is presumably to tighten up security, as the former behavior was the source of tapjacking attacks. I wrote [a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/03/03/tapjacking-defunct.html) recently about this change.

> Any idea's?

Don't use either of them.

Comment: I just found a app that still does it in ICS, Swipepad.
It allows to drag in every app from a pre-defined point to to the middle of the screen and then start a overlay, so there must be a way

Comment: @EdwinSchriek: That behavior sounds consistent with `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` -- it seems reasonable that continuous touch events started via a tap on a system alert would be delivered to that system alert and not an underlying app.

Comment: hmm, i guess it's not possible then, but i will keep looking. Thanks!

Comment: @Edwin Schriek, Can you help me to solve my question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405516/touch-event-getaction-does-not-work-under-service-class-in-android-studio

Answer (score 24):

To create an overlay view, when setting up the LayoutParams
**DON'T** set the type to `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

Instead set it to `TYPE_PHONE`.

Use the following flags:

`FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`

`FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`

`FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`  << I found this one to be quite important.  Without it, focus is given to the overlay and soft-key (home, menu, etc.) presses are not passed to the activity below.

Comment: FYI jawsware has a full sample app here that works for ICS: http://www.jawsware.mobi/code_OverlayView/

Comment: Not able to catch click events on any of the veiws in it on 4.2.X, though works well on lower versions of Android. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me - I had 'TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY' and I changed it to 'TYPE_PHONE' with 'FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL' and set listener with 'setOnTouchListener' instead of 'setOnClickListener' to receive touches in a PopUp windows above my activity as well as in the activity below. In my case it was a default system incoming call notification with an overlaying window.

Comment: @kosiara, were you able to prevent Home Button click?

Comment: @jawsware, do you know maybe how to prevent Home Button click?

Comment: @jawsware , TNX! I was needed only fact of touch - true\false. Now it WORKS !