# TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY in Android 4 ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-windowmanager

My question is similar to the one here, [TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9656185/563306)

but is there any other way to achieve System overlay with touch events in ICS?

There are applications in the market which use overlay like,

Dock4Droid https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.dock

and

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.conduction.swipepad.android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT still works on ICS and I need to come up with a solution using this flag.