# onTouchEvent while app is on pause

Tags: android, touch-event

How do I keep receiving onTouchEvent when my app is in "onPause" or "onStop" status?
In other words, I want to know if I made ACTION_DOWN or such gestures while my app is running on the background. Of course, when I exit the app, it shouldn't work. Can someone help me on this? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a window of type [TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY). You need extra permissions for this. This window will receive the touch events.

**Update:** It seems as this only worked before: [TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656185/type-system-overlay-in-ics/9656233#9656233)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a general system mechanism that can be used for this purpose but it will not work with the normal onTouchEvent. This event is assigned to a view - and this view will not be visible when your App is paused or stopped. So I guess you have to look for some kind of system event and nothing that is assigned to an App-local view.